# How to make data coming in console to reflect on HTML in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a page, where in i have 2 tabs.

1. If the data active value is true, then it must give data to active messages section in HTML.
2. If the data active is false, then it must give data to close messages section in HTML.
   How can i do this?

HTML:

```
<mat-tab label="Active">
  <mat-icon for="search">search</mat-icon>
  <input type="search" name="search" class="search" placeholder="Company">
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let message of activeMessages" (click)="showMessage(message)" [class.activeShow]="message.id == message_id">
      <span>{{message.date}}</span>
      <img src="{{message.image}}" alt="img" />
      <p style="padding-top: 16px;">{{message.name}}</p>
      <p ><b>{{message.subject}}</b></p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</mat-tab>
<mat-tab label="Closed">
  <mat-icon for="search">search</mat-icon>
  <input type="search" name="search" class="search" placeholder="Company">
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let closemessage of closedMessages" (click)="closeMessage(closemessage)" [class.activeShow]="closemessage.id == message_idc">
      <span>{{closemessage.date}}</span>
      <img src="{{closemessage.image}}" alt="img" />
      <p >{{closemessage.name}}</p>
      <p ><b>{{closemessage.subject}}</b></p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</mat-tab>
```

TS:

```
this.service
        .getMessages()
        .subscribe(
          data => {
            this.messagesdata = data;
            console.log(data);
            if(data.active== true) {
              this.activeMessages = this.messagesdata
            }
          },error => {});
  }
```

Console Output:

[image]

Comment: `<mat-tab *ngIf="closemessage" label="Closed">` and `<mat-tab *ngIf="message" label="Active">`

Comment: I am not getting how to fetch data to frontend from console. That i need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your requirement,

After you get the response just filter the `activeMessages` and `closedMessages` and display them as per condition

And you declare variables as `this.message_show` and as the ``` tab`` is changed, you make the ```messages section` to come true there by you get the messages as you wanted.

**Component:**

```
this.service
    .getMessages()
    .subscribe(
    data => {
        this.messagesdata = data;
        let activeMsgs = data.filter(msg => msg.active == true)
        this.activeMessages = activeMsgs;
        console.log(this.activeMessages);
        if (this.activeMessages.length > 0) {
            if (!this.message_show) {
                this.message_show = this.activeMessages[0];
                this.message = true;
                this.message_id = this.activeMessages[0].id
            }
        }
        let closeMsgs = data.filter(msg => msg.active == false)
        this.closedMessages = closeMsgs;
        if (this.closedMessages.length > 0) {
            if (!this.message_close) {
                this.message_close = this.closedMessages[0];
                this.message_idc = this.closedMessages[0].id
            }
        }
        console.log(this.closedMessages);
    }, error => { });
```

Answer (score 1):

Filter your service response like

```
.subscribe(
          data => {
            this.messagesdata = data;
            let activeMsgs = data.filter(msg => msg.active == true)
                                 .map(m => { return m.messages});
            this.activeMessages = [].concat.apply([], activeMsgs);

            let closeMsgs = data.filter(msg => msg.active == false)
                                 .map(m => { return m.messages});
            this.closedMessages = [].concat.apply([], closeMsgs);
         }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, now i am able to seperate messages on basis of true or false. But now, inside the activeMessages data i have messages thing, how do i make that messages part come on my HTML? I tried this, but it didnt work this.activeMessages = data.filter(msg => msg.active == true);
            console.log(this.activeMessages.messsages);

Comment: Updated my answer :D

Comment: Thanks but here it gives only one messages instead of giving all 5

Comment: It is working fine for me. Can you provide your plunkr?

Comment: i will try to do

Comment: Remove messages from {{message.messages.updated_at | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}. Just {{message.updated_at | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}

Comment: I gave like ur first answer, this.messagesdata = data;
                  let activeMsgs = data.filter(msg => msg.active == true)
                  this.activeMessages = activeMsgs; and in html

Comment: <li *ngFor="let message of activeMessages" (click)="showMessage(message)" [class.activeShow]="message.id == message_id">
            {{message.messages|json}}
              <span>{{message.updated_at  | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</span>

Comment: so in html json data was ike this[ { "id": 4, "text": "whhhat", "is_read": false, "conversation_id": 5, "from_user_id": 2, "to_user_id": 1, "created_at": "2018-04-06T12:24:16.251Z", "updated_at": "2018-04-06T12:24:16.25

Comment: so from that array of messages data, how do i fetch for date

Comment: Read this line in my answer.  `this.activeMessages = [].concat.apply([], activeMsgs);`

Comment: ya but in that, i get only messages field, that too only 1 messages section comes.. but in my html in only few fields i fetch messages data from whole data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169557/discussion-between-parshwa-shah-and-bhrungarajni).

Answer (score 0):

json pipe, here is an example on how to show the data's value

```
{{data | json}}
```

Now you can see the data's value like in the console.